# Send email via SmtpClient

Tags: c#, smtpclient

My outlook can send email using my accounts settings.
But I can't send email from C#.

Here is my account settings:

```
Microsoft exchange server: exch.server1.com;
User name: user1@server1.com;
Password: password1;
```

----- Security tab -----

```
Encrypt data between Microsoft Office Outlook and Microsoft Exchange - CHECKED;
Logon network security: Negotiate Authentication;
```

----- Connection tab -----

```
Connect using my Local Area Network (LAN) - SELECTED;
Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP - CHECKED;
```

----- Exchange proxy settings form -----

```
Use this email to connect to my proxy server fo Exchange: https://owa.server1.com
Connect using SSL only - CHECKED;
Only connect to proxy servers that have this principal name in their certificate: msstd:owa.server1.com;
Proxy authentication settings: NTLM Authentication;
```

Here is my C# code:

```
var completeMessage = new MailMessage();
completeMessage.From = new MailAddress("ivanov@server1.com");
completeMessage.To.Add("ivanov@server1.com");
completeMessage.Subject = "test subject";
completeMessage.Body ="test body";
var client = new SmtpClient("exch.server1.com");
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1@server1.com", "password1");
client.Send(completeMessage);
```

The following exception occurs:
`The remote name could not be resolved: 'exch.server1.com'`

This url "exch.server1.com" is blocked from my office.
Please advice me how should I configure SmtpClient to send email.